# Reactive Multi-level List in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a multi-level list in Shiny with the capability to add children to parents but I am unable to have it reactive. Is it possible to have a button in shiny to append a new item indexed by the next integer?

For example:

```
 1.
 1.1
 1.1.1
 1.2
```

With the functionality to "add" a new item under 1.1 indexed 1.1.2 and likewise the capability of 1.2.1 under 1.2 as seen below:

```
 1.
 1.1
 1.1.1
 1.1.2
 1.2
 1.2.1
```

I am trying to have it create a list and then have two action buttons to add/remove the list item in the list.

Comment: How do you decide if you add 1.1.2 or 1.2.1?

Comment: Have an action button appear on every item in the multi-level list to "add" a child to it thus establishing it as the parent. Is this possible or would it be easier to just add another member, the user define the number schema and then the list adjusts to that input?

Comment: i would suggest a selectinput to choose the parent and then add a child to the chosen parent by the action button, what do you think?

Comment: @BigDataScientist that sounds like that would work. How would a selectinput work in shiny with being able to generate something like that? Sorry for my lack of knowledge...

Comment: it was not as straightforward as expected, but i think it should work as planned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store it in a `reactiveValue()` and make the selection via a `selectInput()` as discussed in the comments:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("parent"),
  actionButton("add", "add"),
  actionButton("remove", "remove"),
  verbatimTextOutput("txt")
)
server <- function(input, output){
  global <- reactiveValues(lst = list(list(list(1),list(2), list(3))))

  output$parent <- renderUI({
    selectInput("par", "parent", 1:length(global$lst[[1]]))
  })

  observe({
    if(input$remove){
      isolate({
        lst <- global$lst[[1]]
        len <- as.numeric(input$par)
        lens <- lengths(lst)
        global$lst[[1]][[len]][[lens[len]]] <- NULL
      })
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(input$add){
      isolate({
        lst <- global$lst[[1]]
        len <- as.numeric(input$par)
        lens <- lengths(lst)
        global$lst[[1]][[len]][[lens[len] + 1]] <- "i am the new guy"  
      })
    }
  })


  output$txt <- renderPrint({
    str(global$lst)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That works really well. Thanks @BigDataScientist. I think that this lays a great foundation for what I am wanting to do.

Comment: how would I associate a textInput for all of the created items in the list? Once the hierarchy is created, I want to create an input for each item in the list.